# Convert NAs to 0 in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na

I know this has been asked before, but the answers are always too specific to the OP. I am also somewhat new to this.

I have a list `WaFrames` of 180 data frames. I need to affect them all because manually takes far too long.

The basic `df[is.na(df)] <- 0`works fine on one frame but I'm  stuck when i'm trying to get it to work over every frame in the list. I've tried all the `lapply` ways and tried for loops. I'm stumped.

Also an answer could lead me to how to make other sweeping changes to all the frames at once.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `lapply(WaFrames, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @akrun Thanks! This did loop through and didn’t give an error, but it didn’t make the change. I’m wondering if I need to stick it in something like for (i in WaFrames).

Comment: You need to assign it i.t. `waFrames[] <- lapply(WaFrames, ...`

Comment: Thank you, again! That is a huge face palm moment. This worked.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
x <- dplyr::data_frame(a = c(NA, 1, 2, NA),
                       b = c(1, 2, NA, 3))
y <- dplyr::data_frame(a = c(NA, 3, 4, NA),
                       b = c(1, 2, NA, 3))

listy <- list(x, y)
func <- function(df){
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
}
purrr::map(listy, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
```

Comment: Ah, just saw that akrun did something similar in the comments. His is probably better, no extra libraries and whatnot!

Comment: Still, thank you. I may still try this. I appreciate the feedback.